# No need to use const & for STL container parameters as we have move semantics?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move-semantics

Usually I use this to avoid copying cost:

```
void bar(const string& s);
void foo(const vector<int>& v);
```

Are STL containers in C++11 all support move semantics?

If so, does following code have the same performance as `const &`?

```
void bar(string s);
void foo(vector<int> v);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move semantics don't just magically make your code faster.

With them, calling a function like `void bar(string s)` is faster than it would be if you had to copy your arguments, but only in the case where the argument can be moved. Consider this case:

```
std::string prompt(std::string prompt_text);

void askOnce(std::string question) { prompt(question); }

void askManyTimes(std::string question) {
   for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
       askOnce(question);
   }
}
```

In the case of `askOnce`, the argument can be copied into the function or moved. When it's calling prompt, the argument can be moved.

In `askManyTimes` however, you need to keep the argument around so you can't move, so you actually end up having to create 10 copies of your question for no good reason.

Generally, if you don't need to modify your string or copy it somewhere else, you should still use `const std::string&`; You can leave the reference off if you need to do a copy later on anyway.

Comment: For clarity: nothing is ever moved in the example code, because named variables never bind to rvalue references, so the move constructors will not be invoked.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch Ah. I was under the impression that compilers are allowed to elicit moves if they can prove the object isn't used after the that call, but that doesn't seem to be the case (at least I can't get gcc to do it). In that case, just read the parts in my answer as "could be moved, but won't be".

Comment: the compiler is only allowed to implicitly move when you `return` a named variable (e.g. exactly a statement of the form `return x;`). If you want to tighten up the answer you can just add in the appropriate `std::move` uses to enable moving in the places where it's safe to do so, or even add in an example of moving when you shouldn't (and noting erroneous the results). :)

Answer (score 5):

> Are STL containers in C++11 all support move semantics?

Yes.

> If so, does following code have the same performance as `const &`?

No, if the argument is an **lvalue**. If the argument is an **rvalue**, the performance is *at least* as good.

- In the case of an **lvalue**, the argument *has* to be copied. There's no way around that. The function signature specifies that it doesn't modify its arguments, but a move operation might modify the object that is being moved from.
- In the case of an **rvalue**, the argument can be moved from, if supported.

So if the parameter will be copied inside the function anyway, it is better to pass it by value, so that rvalues can be moved from, while lvalues will still be copied.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you pass in. If you pass a temporary object it will get *moved* in but if you pass a named variable it will get *copied*.

```
bar(func_returns_string()); // move

std::string s;
bar(s); // copy
```

You can force it to *move* a named variable using `std::move`:

```
bar(std::move(s)); // move (now s is empty)
```